# What is the meaning of the final scene of the first season of "House of Cards"?

Tags: analysis, house-of-cards

At the finale of the first season of "House Of Cards", what is the meaning of Frank Underwood running with Claire but slowly leaving her back?

Is it a wink that Frank, although Claire helps him, is only thinking of himself?

Answer (score 3):

This can't objectively be answered, as there is no in-universe explanation. I also cannot find a direct quote by any of the showmakers to confirm or deny this.

However, seeing what happens in the following seasons (most notably the end of season 3) seems to confirm that suspicion. Frank is caught saying things that confirm that he is a bit more selfish than he realizes.

I would say that you are right that this is one of the first hints of Frank's state of mind.